# Does $\sigma (X)\cap \sigma (Y)=\sigma (X,Y)$?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. I'm resding the book of Durrett (probability : application and example). I'm studing random variable and $\sigma -$algebra. Let $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ random variables. I was wondering,

1) Does $$\sigma (X)\cap \sigma (Y)=\sigma (X,Y) \ ?$$

2) Does $$\sigma (X\mid Y\in B)=\sigma (X)\cap \{Y\in B\}=\{X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(B)\mid A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$$

---

**Attempts**

**1)** since $\sigma (X,Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma -$algebra s.t. $X$ and $Y$ are measurable and that $X$ and $Y$ and that $\sigma (X)\cap \sigma (Y)$ is a $\sigma -$algebra contained in $\sigma (X)$ and $\sigma (Y)$, for sure $\sigma (X)\cap \sigma (Y)\subset \sigma (X,Y)$. Now, if $X$ and $Y$ are measurable, of course that we have the equality, but I'm really not sure about that. What I think is that $$\sigma (X,Y)=\sigma (X)\vee\sigma (Y)$$
where $\sigma (X)\vee\sigma (Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma -$ algebra that contain $\sigma (X)$ and $\sigma (Y)$.

**2)** I always heard that $X\mid Y\in B$ is not a $\sigma -$algebra. But alors, I know that if $B\in \mathcal F$, then $\mathcal F_B=\{A\cap B\mid A\in \mathcal F\}$ is a $\sigma -$algebra on $B$ and that $(B,\mathcal F_B,\mathbb P_B)$ where $\mathbb P_B(K)=\frac{\mathbb P(K)}{\mathbb P(B)}$ is a probability space. In in somehow, I would say that $\sigma (X\mid Y\in B)=\sigma (X)\cap\{Y\in B\}$ is indeed true, and is a $\sigma -$algebra on  $Supp(X)$ with probability measure $$\mathbb Q(A)=\frac{\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y\in B\}}{\mathbb P\{X\in B\}}.$$

What do you think ?

Comment: What does $\sigma(X|Y\in B)$ mean?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy 1) is hardly true (... perhaps you mean that the OP's thoughts about 1) are correct...?) Consider e.g. $X=1_{\{0\}}$ and $Y=1_{\{1\}}$ on $\Omega = [0,1]$. Then $\sigma(X) \cap \sigma(Y) = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ is strictly smaller than $\sigma(X,Y)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I would think that $\sigma (X\mid Y\in B)$ is th smallest $\sigma -$algebra that make $X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(B)$ measurable for all $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.